# Graddle missing transitive dependency

Tags: maven, gradle, transitive-dependency

I'm importing a dependency in my project that itself requires another one (com.discord4j). Gradle seems to be aware of this transitive dependency as shown by the output of `gradle dependencies` command below (discord4j is shown as required by com.bancarelvalentin.genericbot at compile and runtime). But i can't import it as its name cannot be resolved.

[image]

I'm no expert when it comes to gradle so i'm most certainly missing something obvious. Anyone can help find what ?

EDIT: After all it seems that the transitive dependency is not add to the compileClasspath. Why ?
[image]

EDIT 2: I fixed the root library POM file; it is available [here](https://gitlab.com/vba-templates/generic-bot/-/packages/720919) but the above screenshot is still what i got in my compileClasspath; I've cleared all caches (InteliJ et Gradle) but nothing will male gradle put that lib in the classpath

```
14:34:16: Executing task 'dependencies'...


> Task :dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

-api (n)
No dependencies

-runtime (n)
No dependencies

annotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'main'.
No dependencies

api - API dependencies for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

apiDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

apiElements - API elements for main. (n)
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts. (n)
No dependencies

compileClasspath - Compile classpath for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)).
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.4.10
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
\--- com.bancarelvalentin:genericbot:0.0.4

compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

compileOnlyDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts. (n)
No dependencies

implementation - Implementation only dependencies for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)). (n)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10 (n)
\--- com.bancarelvalentin:genericbot:0.0.4 (n)

implementationDependenciesMetadata
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.4.10
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
\--- com.bancarelvalentin:genericbot:0.0.4

kotlinCompilerClasspath
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.4.10
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.4.10
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.4.10
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.10
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10 (*)
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.4.10
     \--- org.jetbrains.intellij.deps:trove4j:1.0.20181211

kotlinCompilerPluginClasspath
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable:1.4.10
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable:1.4.10
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-common:1.4.10
     |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10
     |    |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.4.10
     |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7
     |    |         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.71 -> 1.4.10 (*)
     |    |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.71 -> 1.4.10
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-jvm:1.4.10
     |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.4.10
     |    |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10 (*)
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-common:1.4.10 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10 (*)
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7 (*)
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10 (*)

kotlinKlibCommonizerClasspath
\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-klib-commonizer-embeddable:1.4.10
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.4.10
     |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.4.10
          +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10 (*)
          +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.4.10
          +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.10
          |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10 (*)
          +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.4.10
          \--- org.jetbrains.intellij.deps:trove4j:1.0.20181211

kotlinNativeCompilerPluginClasspath
No dependencies

kotlinScriptDef - Script filename extensions discovery classpath configuration
No dependencies

kotlinScriptDefExtensions
No dependencies

runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)).
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.4.10
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
\--- com.bancarelvalentin:genericbot:0.0.4
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10 (*)
     +--- com.discord4j:discord4j-core:3.1.0
     |    +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10
     |    |    +--- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:3.3.3.RELEASE (c)
     |    |    +--- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:0.9.10.RELEASE (c)
     |    |    +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.3.8.RELEASE (c)
     |    |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.3 (c)
     |    +--- com.discord4j:discord-json:1.5.3
     |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.11.1
     |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.1
     |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1
     |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.1
     |    |    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.1
     |    |    +--- com.discord4j:discord-json-api:1.5.3
     |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.11.1 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1 (*)
     |    +--- com.discord4j:discord4j-rest:3.1.0
     |    |    +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.discord4j:discord-json:1.5.3 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.discord4j:discord4j-common:3.1.0
     |    |         +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10 (*)
     |    |         +--- com.discord4j:discord-json:1.5.3 (*)
     |    |         +--- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:0.9.10.RELEASE
     |    |         |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-resolver:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |         \--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-resolver:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |         \--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    +--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    +--- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |         \--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    \--- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.3.8.RELEASE
     |    |         |         \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.3
     |    |         +--- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:3.3.3.RELEASE
     |    |         |    \--- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.3.4.RELEASE -> 3.3.8.RELEASE (*)
     |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1 (*)
     |    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.11.1 (*)
     |    +--- com.discord4j:discord4j-gateway:3.1.0
     |    |    +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.discord4j:discord-json:1.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.discord4j:discord4j-common:3.1.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:3.3.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- com.discord4j:discord4j-voice:3.1.0
     |    |    +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.discord4j:discord-json:1.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.discord4j:discord4j-common:3.1.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.discord4j:simple-fsm:1.0.1
     |    \--- com.discord4j:stores-jdk:3.1.3
     |         +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10 (*)
     |         \--- com.discord4j:stores-api:3.1.3
     |              +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10 (*)
     |              +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.3.8.RELEASE (*)
     |              +--- com.austinv11.servicer:Servicer:1.0.3
     |              \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
     +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
     |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
     \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30

runtimeElements - Elements of runtime for main. (n)
No dependencies

runtimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for compilation 'main' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

runtimeOnlyDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

sourceArtifacts (n)
No dependencies

testAnnotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'test'.
No dependencies

testApi - API dependencies for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

testApiDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)).
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.4.10
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
\--- com.bancarelvalentin:genericbot:0.0.4

testCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

testCompileOnlyDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

testImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

testImplementationDependenciesMetadata
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.4.10
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
\--- com.bancarelvalentin:genericbot:0.0.4

testKotlinScriptDef - Script filename extensions discovery classpath configuration
No dependencies

testKotlinScriptDefExtensions
No dependencies

testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)).
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.4.10
|    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
\--- com.bancarelvalentin:genericbot:0.0.4
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10 (*)
     +--- com.discord4j:discord4j-core:3.1.0
     |    +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10
     |    |    +--- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:3.3.3.RELEASE (c)
     |    |    +--- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:0.9.10.RELEASE (c)
     |    |    +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.3.8.RELEASE (c)
     |    |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.3 (c)
     |    +--- com.discord4j:discord-json:1.5.3
     |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.11.1
     |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.1
     |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1
     |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.1
     |    |    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.1
     |    |    +--- com.discord4j:discord-json-api:1.5.3
     |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.11.1 (*)
     |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1 (*)
     |    +--- com.discord4j:discord4j-rest:3.1.0
     |    |    +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.discord4j:discord-json:1.5.3 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.discord4j:discord4j-common:3.1.0
     |    |         +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10 (*)
     |    |         +--- com.discord4j:discord-json:1.5.3 (*)
     |    |         +--- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:0.9.10.RELEASE
     |    |         |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-resolver:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |         \--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-resolver:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |         \--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    +--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    +--- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.51.Final
     |    |         |    |         +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    |         \--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.51.Final (*)
     |    |         |    \--- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.3.8.RELEASE
     |    |         |         \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.3
     |    |         +--- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:3.3.3.RELEASE
     |    |         |    \--- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.3.4.RELEASE -> 3.3.8.RELEASE (*)
     |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1 (*)
     |    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.11.1 (*)
     |    +--- com.discord4j:discord4j-gateway:3.1.0
     |    |    +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.discord4j:discord-json:1.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.discord4j:discord4j-common:3.1.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra:3.3.3.RELEASE (*)
     |    +--- com.discord4j:discord4j-voice:3.1.0
     |    |    +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.discord4j:discord-json:1.5.3 (*)
     |    |    +--- com.discord4j:discord4j-common:3.1.0 (*)
     |    |    \--- com.discord4j:simple-fsm:1.0.1
     |    \--- com.discord4j:stores-jdk:3.1.3
     |         +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10 (*)
     |         \--- com.discord4j:stores-api:3.1.3
     |              +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-bom:Dysprosium-SR10 (*)
     |              +--- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.3.8.RELEASE (*)
     |              +--- com.austinv11.servicer:Servicer:1.0.3
     |              \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
     +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3
     |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
     \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30

testRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for compilation 'test' (target  (jvm)). (n)
No dependencies

testRuntimeOnlyDependenciesMetadata
No dependencies

(c) - dependency constraint
(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

(n) - Not resolved (configuration is not meant to be resolved)

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 116ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
14:34:16: Task execution finished 'dependencies'.
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the published pom of the `com.bancarelvalentin:genericbot` ?

if `genericbot` module has only `runtime` dependencies then you won't see them in your compile class path and hence IDE wont detect them.

Comment: I edited the genericbot (now named discordbot) publishing mechanism to set the scope to compile. You can see the registry (with the latest POM) here: https://gitlab.com/vba-templates/generic-bot/-/packages - But when i import it in my other project it's still not in the compile classpath (cf, previous screen) - The version as i write this is 0.0.11

Comment: After few more tweaks to my build.gradle in the discordbot; my POM is finally exactly what i want it to be without some shady workaround; see https://gitlab.com/vba-templates/generic-bot/-/packages/720923.  -  But I cannot manage to make this work

Comment: the gitlab link gives 404

Comment: Not the first one. Anyway, I find out that the final problem was not in the dependency but in my project. I imported a dependency alreay present as a transitive dep to my bot; so discord was not compilling any of those transitives.